# Can i use breeze.js with SQLite or local database?

Tags: breeze, hottowel

I am using HotTowel for developing for an offline online scenario for application i am working with .

I would like to know if I can use existing HotTowel stack along with Breeze for querying my offline database.

Please let us know if anyone has such exposure if I can combine both offline and online scenario with breeze and implement scenario effectively.

Answer (score 0):

To help you implement offline/online solution with breeze you should use MetadataStore's export facility to export your entities as string, store your entities in your offline database and then import them back to MetadataStore. More on this topic please read [export and import entities](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/exportimport)